# Excel: If Cell A Matches Cell B, Then add text to Cell C

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

IF Cell Sheet1!A1 MATCHES the Value in Cell Sheet2!B1, THEN add string 
", quantity:"&Sheet2!D1
to the end of the existing value in Cell Sheet1!C1

So for example:

**Sheet 1 - original**:

```
Col A   Col B   Col C
 123            Blue
 444            Large
 758            Pink
```

**Sheet 2 - original**:

```
Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D
         758             500
         123             750
         758             100
```

**Sheet 1 - After Macro**:

```
Col A   Col B   Col C
 123            Blue, quantity: 750
 444            Large, quantity: 100
 758            Pink, quantity: 500
```

Is this type of cross-sheet formula possible? I've searched the site and haven't found quite the scenario I'm trying to code. I've done something similar within the same sheet and with an empty Cell C, but never quite like this...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the problem you are having with your existing code?

Comment: This should get you started: `If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value2 = Sheet2.Range("B1").Value2 Then Sheet1.Range("C1").Value2 = Sheet1.Range("C1").Value2 & ", quantity:" & Sheet2.Range("D1")`

Answer (score 0):

**Macro**

This is quite possible with a macro, as you request, but in this case a macro is not needed at all if you just want to show these values. In case you really need to change the original content then you need a macro. However, this problem is quite easy using regular Excel formulas and functions.

**Formula**
if you need to show a value in a cell concatenated with another value, you can either use the `CONCATENATE` function, or use the `&` operator.

Example

```
=CONCATENATE(C3,",",A3)
```

Anywhere in Excel where you can use cells, you can also use full references including the sheet name. Like so

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet2!C3,",",Sheet1!A3)
```

If you prefer to use the `&` operator, you can do the previous example like so:

```
=Sheet2!C3 & "," & Sheet1!A3
```

You can always hide the original column and only show the concatenated version using the formula in the column next to it.

**Improvements**
I would encourage you to look into the use of *Tables* instead of *Ranges*. Just click on *Insert > Table* in the menu and you will have a table with extra functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here, my pure vba approach for your problem:

```
Public Sub getQuantity()

    Dim sh1, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim foundCell As Range

    'Set sheets
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    'set the start row for Sheet1
    startRow = 1

    'loop until column A of Sheet1 is blank
    Do While sh1.Range("A" & startRow) <> ""

        'search id of column A from column B of Sheet2
        Set foundCell = sh2.Range("B:B").Find(sh1.Range("A" & startRow), LookIn:=xlValues)

        'If match id is found, add quantity in column C of Sheet1.
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then

            sh1.Range("C" & startRow) = sh1.Range("C" & startRow) & ", quantity:" & foundCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

        End If

        'increase row
        startRow = startRow + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```